# running Selenium test case on console throwing lot of errors

Tags: java, selenium, console, selenium-webdriver

Looks like a silly question but I am really stuck and any help would be appreciated .

I exported a selenium test case as **Junit 4 Web driver** and I ran it using **eclipse** it runs properly and does all the appropriate task intended to do . But if I try running it using **console** it throws loads of errors .

Something like :

> editCampaign.java:318: cannot find symbol
>   symbol  : variable By
>   location: class org.openqa.selenium.example.editCampaign 
>                          driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();

Comment: Can you post the command you are using in the console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you simply missing web driver libraries in classpath (class 'By' in your case), try to add

```
-classpath librariesDirectory
```

to your execution command

Comment: Mudalov , Thanks but Can you please elaborate as i am a fresher .

Comment: Could you please post your command line string for example. E.g.
>java ClassName

Comment: i was trying to do :
javac editCampaign.java

But i am unable to get any output throws a lot of errors . While on running it on eclipse it does not show any error

Comment: Please try to add Web Driver folder to class path. E.g.
javac -classpath C:/selenium/webDriver.jar editCampaign.java

Answer (score 0):

It looks like he can't find the element "submit" by id. Try to look for it with CSS selector.
It should be something like that

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='submit']"));
```